# How does forecast() of a tslm() model decide how many periods to forecast?

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

What is happening under the hood here with the h values?
If you could point me to the documentation that describes this I would really appreciate it! Thanks

```
library(forecast)
model <- tslm(USAccDeaths ~ trend + season)
forecast(model)                               # returns 12 months of forecasts
forecast(model, h=0)                          # returns  2 months of forecasts
forecast(model, h=1)                          # returns  1 month  of forecasts
forecast(model, h=2)                          # returns  2 months of forecasts (same as h=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default forecast horizon is 10 months, not 12.
`h=0` is a bug, which I have fixed in https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/commit/4ed33c167822ba503bc4a6fdcac2b04cd5018459

All other forecast horizons (1, 2, ...) are behaving as expected.

```r
library(forecast)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo
model <- tslm(USAccDeaths ~ trend + season)
forecast(model)
#>          Point Forecast    Lo 80     Hi 80    Lo 95     Hi 95
#> Jan 1979       7557.275 6917.525  8197.025 6569.565  8544.985
#> Feb 1979       6797.108 6157.358  7436.858 5809.399  7784.818
#> Mar 1979       7575.608 6935.858  8215.358 6587.899  8563.318
#> Apr 1979       7788.608 7148.858  8428.358 6800.899  8776.318
#> May 1979       8637.608 7997.858  9277.358 7649.899  9625.318
#> Jun 1979       9108.608 8468.858  9748.358 8120.899 10096.318
#> Jul 1979       9966.108 9326.358 10605.858 8978.399 10953.818
#> Aug 1979       9262.442 8622.692  9902.192 8274.732 10250.151
#> Sep 1979       8213.608 7573.858  8853.358 7225.899  9201.318
#> Oct 1979       8503.442 7863.692  9143.192 7515.732  9491.151
forecast(model, h=0)
#> Error in forecast.lm(model, h = 0): The forecast horizon must be at least 1.
forecast(model, h=1)
#>          Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
#> Jan 1979       7557.275 6917.525 8197.025 6569.565 8544.985
forecast(model, h=2)
#>          Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
#> Jan 1979       7557.275 6917.525 8197.025 6569.565 8544.985
#> Feb 1979       6797.108 6157.358 7436.858 5809.399 7784.818
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Mitchell I really appreciate the link you shared above. I studied it and played around with the data more and I think I almost get it. The forecast() with a ts produces estimates using ets for 2 x frequency periods into the future. In contrast the forecast() with tslm produces an estimates generated by the tslm model for 10 periods into the future. Am I correct?

Comment: That is correct. You can see the default values in the help files, for example `?forecast::forecast.lm` shows a simple default of `h=10`. There are many inconsistencies in the forecast package, which is partly why we now recommend using the fable package for forecasting (and if you're new to forecasting, the fpp3 textbook is a great resource and source of documentation).

Comment: Sweet! I can't wait to dive into fpp3. Thanks again!